# Reports in rml of Openerp

Tags: report, odoo, rml

In my purchase order report template i have a table that displays purchase order line details.that is the products i added in the purchase order.but when a minimum of 20 products is added the products in the template just overwritten on the footer of my purchase order template.
i used  tag for breaking page but didnt work.

```
<condPageBreak height="600"/>
```

any help?

Comment: Help get the StackExchange OpenERP site going: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43481/openerp?referrer=CbZ7bL3fh2QdmpKS2kqovw2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the height of the frame the problem gets resolved.
my original frame id defenition was as follows:

```
<frame id="first" x1="34.0" y1="28.0" width="530" height="786"/>
```

i changed the above to the below one:

```
<frame id="first" x1="18.0" y1="42.0" width="535" height="600"/>
```