# WebKit report table header on every page

Tags: webkit, odoo

I have created web kit report for HR Timesheet Employees Attendance.I have generated report having 10 pages. But I face little problem over here,report contains a table which is continue in next pages.It is dynamic.So The problem is on the next page table header is not shown.

I want to show table header on every page if the table continues on next pages.

Comment: An interesting problem with WebKit. Have you found a WebKit solution @Abhishek?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like table headers are a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=566) with webkit. That bug report does suggest some workarounds, but they don't sound very promising.

If you decide to go back to the RML reports, the [ReportLab documentation](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) describes the `repeatRows` attribute for a `blockTable`.

> The `repeatRows` argument specifies the number of leading rows that should be repeated when the `Table` is asked to split itself. The `repeatCols` argument is currently ignored as a `Table` cannot be split by column.

I haven't tried it myself, but it also appears in some of the [OpenERP documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/05_reports.html).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by dynamic rows, @AbhishekMehta. Does the [repeatIn function](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/3_11_reports/11_1_openoffice_report.html#dynamic-content-in-openoffice-reports) do what you need?

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
But I made webkit report using report_webkit module of operERP.The problem is not in page header it is in table header.I want table header on each page if table continues on next pages and I have a mako file not rml file.

Comment: Actually It is a Timesheet Report so we have to select one month and multiple employees so columns and rows are dynamic like if month is january then columns will be 31 days and if month is February then columns will be 28 or 29.

Comment: That should be possible in an RML file, @AbhishekMehta. If that's the only reason you chose webkit, then I suggest you ask a separate question on how to do that in RML. The more details you give about your report, the more helpful the answer is likely to be.

Comment: Ya you are right may be but actually my superiors wants this report compulsorily in webkit and apart from table heading it almost completed.

Answer (score 0):

ok so u have tables that repeats and currently its overwritten on the header of you page template ...the problem is with the frame height just adjust the frame height a bit less than the current value in the rml file.
for eg:

```
<frame id="first" x1="18.0" y1="42.0" width="535" height="600"/>
```

it will get solved i too had the same problem and solved it by adjusting the frame id. this is the link of the question i asked: [Reports in rml of Openerp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332293/reports-in-rml-of-openerp)

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
But I made webkit or is this solution work for that and Table header was invisible not Page header.

Comment: ok then try repeat rows including the table header or can you just paste the code?